# How do I set the CMake executable in VS Code?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, cmake

I'm using the CMake Tools extension in VS Code to build and run a C++ project on WSL ssh remote.

Where do I set the cmake executable to use?

On Build, CMake Tools executes

`[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/g++ /remote/work/private/software/repo -G "Unix Makefiles"`

But the issue is I need to call cmake3 directly. I do not control the ssh remote machine, and cannot remove cmake2 (which is what the default proc is calling).

When I run this on the remote host I explicitly call cmake3, and would like to do the same here, should be easy enough to change the proc command to cmake3 instead of cmake but I cannot find the option anywhere.

Searched around the settings, and tried calling cmake3 in terminal then just build, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `cmake.cmakePath` setting. Quoting [the docs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings):

> | Setting | Description | Default value | Supports substitution |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `cmake.cmakePath` | Specify location of the cmake executable. | `cmake` (causes CMake Tools to search the `PATH` environment variable, as well as some hard-coded locations.) | Supports substitution for `workspaceRoot`, `workspaceFolder`, `workspaceRootFolderName`, `userHome`, `${command:...}` and `${env:...}`. Other substitutions result in an empty string. |